# TouchXML problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, touchxml

I have got following xml which I need to parse using TouchXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<categories>
    <category0>
    <title>Alcoholic Drinks</title>
        <description>Buy beers, wines, sprits and champagne from the top online alocholic drink stores.&#xD;
                 Whatever your tipple you are sure to find a drinks supplier from our top shops below:
        </description>
        <status>1</status>
        <popularStatus></popularStatus>
        <order></order>
        <link>alcoholic-drinks</link>
        <id>1</id>
    </category0>
    <category1>
        <title>Art and Collectibles</title>
        <description>Are you looking to buy contemporary or fine art, or do you prefer to make your own artwork?&# 
                &#xD;
                Whether type of artwork or craft materials you are looking for, you are certain to find one of the shops below more than helpful:
        </description>
        <status>1</status>
        <popularStatus></popularStatus>
        <order></order>
        <link>art-and-collectibles</link>
        <id>2</id>
    </category1>
    <category2>
        <title>Auctions</title>
        <description>Are you looking for the UK's biggest and best Auction Sites?&#xD;
                The team at safebuyer.co.uk have scoured the web to find the UK's favourite auctions, so why wait, start your bidding now!
        </description>
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

I am thinking to create two loops from root node in order to fetch title and link but coudnt figure out how to do it. Can anybody help please.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your XML file and make all the category tag same. You can put all ... Instead of ... and   ....

So that would be pretty easy to parse. You just need to make category class and all the tag would be parse automatically if you have correct xml parsing code.

Comment: I cant change XML. Can you help in parsing current XML?

Comment: You can use this library to parse your xml. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 1):

```
CXMLNode *node;
for(i=0; i<10 ; i++){
    NSString *xpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//category%d/title", i]; 
    NSArray *title = [[node nodesForXPath:xpath] stringValue];
}
```

Use the above code..

Answer (score 0):

```
CXMLElement *element;
NSArray *titleItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[element nodesForXPath:@"//category" error:nil]];  
for(CXMLElement *item in titleItems){
NSString *title = [[item selectSingleNode:@"title"] stringValue];

}
```

Note: category node should be repeating.....

Comment: nodes are named <category0>, <category1> and so on so I cant use your xpath

Comment: CXMLNode *node; for(i=0; i<10 ; i++){ NSString *xpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//category%d/title", i]; NSArray *title = [[node nodesForXPath:xpath] stringValue]; }

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives you a dictionary where keys are titles and data are the links. Of course, if your XML document is "big", this is not the best way to do it.

```
CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:theXML options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
NSArray *categories = nil;
NSMutableDictionary* results = nil;
categories = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/categories/*[starts-with(name(), 'category')]" error:nil];
if (categories != nil && [categories count] > 0)
{
         results = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[categories count]];
         for (CXMLElement *category in categories)
         {
              NSArray* titles = [category elementsForName:@"title"];
              if ([titles count] >0)
              {
                   NSArray* links = [category elementsForName:@"link"];
                   [result setObject:([links count]>0?[[links objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]:nil;
                           forKey:[[titles objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]];
              } 
         }
}
```